# how do you get a reference to an outer div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

if i have this html

```
<div class="whole">This is a <div class="min">Test</div></div>
```

i want to change the html of the "whole" div when i click on the "min" div:

i have tried this below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.min').live('click', function() {
         $(this).prev('.whole').html("<img  BORDER=0 src='../../images/copy1.png' />");
    });
});
```

does anyone have any ideas on whats going wrong here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), not `prev`. Your `div.min` is inside, not next to, the `div.whole`. So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.min').live('click', function() {
         $(this).parent('.whole').html("<img  BORDER=0 src='../../images/copy1.png' />");
    });
});
```

---

2017 update: `live` has been deprecated for years and was eventually removed. It's used in the above because it was in the OP's original code and wasn't the issue, but just for completeness, the current way to do this is with `on`'s delegation signature:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.min', function() {
     $(this).parent('.whole').html("<img  BORDER=0 src='../../images/copy1.png' />");
});
```

Note that we don't even need the `ready`, since this is doing event delegation on `document`, so it doesn't have to wait. (That was true of the `live` version above as well.)

Answer (score 5):

`.prev()` will select the *preceding sibling*, i.e. the element that precedes the current element at **the same level**.
You are looking for **[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**.

E.g.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

- `$('#second').prev()` will select `#first`.
- `$('#second').parent()` will select `#parent`.
- `$('#first').next()` will select `#second`.

Answer (score -1):

Another way of doing this would be the follow

```
$('div.min').click(function(event){
   if ($(event.target).is('div.min')){
        $('div.whole').html("<img  BORDER=0 src='../../images/copy1.png' />");
        }
});​
```